# SELinux - How to avoid it preventing a process from write access on newly created files into folder

Tags: java, selinux, lock

I'm hardly trying to correctly use `selinux` keeping it in enforced mode, but very often I encounter issues with it causing our application to work improperly.

Our web application is java backend and `angular` front end, deployed on `tomcat` and `apache httpd`, the backend use `lucene` as a search engine which create a file into a filesystem folder every time a re-index is performed. Oh yes, the server is CentOS7 if this matters.

for the growth of others I say that reading the subhuman SELinux log `/var/log/audit/audit.log` is useless, and you must before traslate it into human using the command:

```
sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log > /var/log/audit/audit_human_readable.log
```

In my case the log was saying the follow:

```
SELinux is preventing /whatever/jre/bin/java from write access on the file /opt/whatever/write.lock
```

and suggesting to fix the issue by:

```
If you want to allow java to have write access on the write.lock file
Then you need to change the label on /opt/whatever/write.lock
Do
# semanage fcontext -a -t FILE_TYPE '/opt/whatever/write.lock'
where FILE_TYPE is one of the following: afs_cache_t, initrc_tmp_t, pki_common_t, pki_ra_log_t, pki_tomcat_cert_t, pki_tomcat_etc_rw_t, pki_tomcat_log_t, pki_tomcat_var_lib_t, pki_tps_log_t$
Then execute:
restorecon -v '/opt/whatever/write.lock'
```

Which looks like a pretty nice and complete suggestion, except that in the past I already executed this suggestion, but on the parent folder hoping this would be applied on childs too, but the issue is still there.

I believe the issue still exists because Lucene through the java process often re-create the write.lock file, very often, everytime a new reindex is performed, and that's mean everytime a new file is uploaded into webapplication which is part of the main functionalities of it. And recreating this file the SElinux context is not inherited correctly.

How can I configure, that every file created under a certain folder, will inherit a specific SElinux context from it's parent directory?

EDIT: (audit.log)

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1528202320.971:33808): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=31394 comm="java" name="index" dev="dm-0" ino=57073 scontext=system_u:system_r:tomcat_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1528202320.971:33808): avc:  denied  { remove_name } for  pid=31394 comm="java" name="write.lock" dev="dm-0" ino=57076 scontext=system_u:system_r:tomcat_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=AVC msg=audit(1528202320.971:33808): avc:  denied  { unlink } for  pid=31394 comm="java" name="write.lock" dev="dm-0" ino=57076 scontext=system_u:system_r:tomcat_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1528202320.971:33808): arch=c000003e syscall=87 success=yes exit=0 a0=7f4a549d8db0 a1=7f4a8c92e1c8 a2=0 a3=3536353030303030 items=2 ppid=1 pid=31394 auid=4294967295 uid=91 gid=91 euid=91 suid=91 fsuid=91 egid=91 sgid=91 fsgid=91 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="java" exe="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64/jre/bin/java" subj=system_u:system_r:tomcat_t:s0 key=(null)
```

EDIT 2: (ps -auxZ)

```
# ps -auxZ | grep tomcat
system_u:system_r:tomcat_t:s0   tomcat    1026  1.2 30.7 9637644 7535952 ?     Ssl  May09 514:38 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -(and so on)
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 root 31648 0.0  0.0 112712 976 pts/0 S+ 14:58   0:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
```

Comment: Please also provide the raw output of audit.log file (or use something like `ausearch -m avc -i`)

Comment: thank you for the answer, updated the question whit new info

Comment: If I understand that well the `java` process is labeled as `tomcat_t`? (you can check that with `ps auxZ`)

Comment: yes exactly man updating the question

Answer (score 2):

I believe the main problem is that your java installation is not properly labeled.

The easiest way of fixing this is to install the Oracle JRE/JDK RPM instead of using the tarball/zip file, or at least install the java directory in `/usr/java`

Otherwise you should probably label the `/whatever/jre/bin` directory and all the content as `bin_t` for that you can see tonioc reply in this thread and do

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t "/whatever/jre/bin(/.*)?"
# restorecon -R -v /whatever/jre/bin
```

Edit, you might want to do that as well:

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t lib_t "/whatever/jre/lib(/.*)?"
```

Comment: Thank you for your usefull replies, just to be sure, the following will not work? `semanage fcontext -a -t tomcat_t "/opt/whatever(/.*)?"` && `semanage fcontext -a -t tomcat_t "/opt/whatever(/.*)?"` Just wondering because I believe the issue is the context of /opt/whatever/write.lock file is wrong since recreated each time very often

Comment: PS: my java installation was very standard `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 tomcat.noarch` using the default centOS 7 repositories

Comment: no, `tomcat_t` should only be used by the scripts starting tomcat, not by the java executable itself

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you want files in /opt/whatever to get context whatever_t , the commands would be:

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t whatever_t "/opt/whatever(/.*)?"
# restorecon -R -v /opt/whatever
```

This should do what you expect. See [man semanage-fcontext](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/semanage-fcontext.8.html)